# how to communicate with embedded activity

Tags: android

In my current project I have a full screen TabActivity. Each tab content is handled by two instances of same `ListActivity`. Now, I put an extra int in intent to know which data should be displayed.
So in `onCreate()` method of my `ListActivity`, I check the int in extra and I build my query to obtain a SQLLiteCursor.

I would like to dynamycally give to this two instances of `ListActivity` the list of item that should be displayed.

I do not know what is the best way to do this. Any idea ?

Regards,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Each tab content is handled by two
>   instances of same ListActivity.

Why not just use `ListViews` as the contents of the tabs? Why make your job so much harder by wrapping those `ListViews` each in a `ListActivity`, then having to work around the fact that you wrapped each in a `ListActivity`?

Get rid of the `ListActivity` classes. Put two `ListViews` as the contents of your tabs. Hand the `Adapters` to those `ListViews` in your `TabActivity` (or regular activity that is using a `TabHost`).

Comment: I'll try it. Thanks for the idea. Actually, I just started Androïd development I did not know the godd practices.

Regards

Comment: Sorry, it's just that I keep seeing developers use the activities-as-tabs pattern, and it drives me batty.

Comment: So it works !
I use two SimpleCursorAdapters for my lists and I can change list content with the changeCursor method.

Thank you.